# Why does Chrome inspector only shows image the second time you click it?

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed that my chrome inspector - that works on both my macbook pro and imac (and previous a pc) doesn't show the image when I click the image link under element tag until the second time I click it.

To those who are confused what I am talking about, chrome allows you to click on a image link when inspecting an element under it's "elements" tag, and jump to resource. My observation is that the first time jumping to the resource tag it gives me a blank page, and the second time (when I go back to the elements tab and click the same link again) it shows the image.

Is this a common bug or some odd setting? Or would it be a website's prevention system?

Photo One
[image: Clicking a link to the photo.]

Photo Two
[image: But altering clicking the first time shows nothing]

Photo Three
[image: If I go back and click again it works!]

Comment: I can’t reproduce that; it always shows the image in the Resources tab the first time. This makes sense because if it can show it in the page, then it has already loaded it, so it should be able to show it in the Resources tab as well. Does this happen on all sites for you? Does it happen all the time? Are your memory and CPU loads high?

Comment: Yes it does happen on all webpages even this one. No my CPU and memory loads very low. I of course already tried disabling all the extensions.

Comment: Curious. Perhaps it’s some security software like a firewall or anti-virus that’s interfering. But then, like I said, if it’s already loaded the image to display in a page, then why wouldn’t it be able to show it in the Resources tab? ಠ_ఠ Incidentally, I *do* always have to click the `[Translate]` button twice. Whenever Chrome asks if I want to translate a page, the first time I click it, it *never* works, and I always have to click it a second time. I guess Chrome’s just wonky and buggy. And with the fascist attitude of the devs, maybe it’s time to give up on Chrome and switch to Firefox. ¬_¬

Comment: It doesn't show the picture in inspector because the first time I click the link it doesn't go down to the tree to find the picture...

Comment: I feels like every time I click the link the inspector should do two things - one, go to the resource tab, two go down to the resource tree to find the image - but in reality it does only one thing at a time.

Comment: Does it show the picture in the pop-up bubble when you hover the cursor over the URL in the Elements tab?

Comment: It does, I uploaded a photo.

Comment: Does it still do it if you switch back to the Elements tab and click the URL again? You said it did the same thing on a PC as well right?